# Manipulating dataframe in python for Glicko calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to run Glicko v2 calculations on a dataframe that I've loaded into python. Since each race is independent, I can only compare athletes that've competed in the same race.

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel("MyDirectory/sample.xlsx")
```

---

```
Athlete Race_Id  Rank  Ranking       RD
   A   Race1     1     1500   0.0000
   B   Race1     2     1350  27.3220
   C   Race1     3     1700  11.2342
   D   Race2     1     1480  80.8880
   E   Race2     2     1500   0.8923
   F   Race2     3     1325   8.0090
```

My desired output would look something like this.

```
Athlete1 Race_Id Ranking  RD Athlete2 Ranking 2 RD2
   A     Race1   1500   0.0000    B    1350  27.3220
   A     Race1   1500   0.0000    C    1700  11.2342
   B     Race1   1350  27.3220    C    1700  11.2342
   D     Race2   1480  80.8880    E    1500   0.8923
   D     Race2   1480  80.8880    F    1700  11.2342
   E     Race2   1500   0.8923    F    1700  11.2342
```

My thinking behind this was that if I had manipulated the dataframe to look like the one above I could easily define functions with my desired calculations and apply them to said dataframe.

In order to get my desired dataframe. I thought I'd reference the last line of each race and create a for loop which matches elements of a dataframe.

```
data_lr= df.groupby(['Race_Id']).tail(1)

Athlete Race_Id  Rank  Ranking       RD
    C   Race1     3     1700  11.2342
    F   Race2     3     1325   8.0090
```

Where I struggle is creating the for loop needed to create my new dataframe? Any guidance would be appreciated or different methods to complete my goal would also be beneficial. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a cartesian self-join and filtering to create your resulting dataframe:

```
(df.merge(df, on='Race_Id',suffixes=('1','2'))
   .query('Rank1 != Rank2 and Athlete1 < Athlete2')
   [['Athlete1','Race_Id','Ranking1','RD1','Athelete2','Ranking2','RD2']])
```

## Update for dynamic suffixes

```
(df.merge(df, on='Race_Id',suffixes=df.Race_Id.str.extract('Race(\d+)')[0].unique())
   .query('Rank1 != Rank2 and Athlete1 < Athlete2')
   [['Athlete1','Race_Id','Ranking1','RD1','Athlete2','Ranking2','RD2']])
```

Output:

```
   Athlete1 Race_Id  Ranking1      RD1 Athlete2  Ranking2      RD2
1         A   Race1      1500   0.0000        B      1350  27.3220
2         A   Race1      1500   0.0000        C      1700  11.2342
5         B   Race1      1350  27.3220        C      1700  11.2342
10        D   Race2      1480  80.8880        E      1500   0.8923
11        D   Race2      1480  80.8880        F      1325   8.0090
14        E   Race2      1500   0.8923        F      1325   8.0090
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Say if I had 500 races...would there be a more user friendly method of getting my desired dataframe instead of typing suffixes=('1','2','3,'....'500')